# How to get element from array stored in dataframe column and split it by space?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need help in the following scenario:

There is one dataframe with the name **df**. It has a column with the name **input** which is in an array format as shown below. I want to split it over space and get the first element of split data in the output. The example is shown below:

Input:

```
[null,'ABC TGF FDSERV',' GHD FGVCF TR UYF']
[null,'GTR ygvv',' HYTR FGVF','GTF BGHY GHYN']
[null]
[null,'GTY DFERFT GHU FRTG']
```

Output:

```
ABC,GHD
GTR, HYTR,GTF
null
GTY
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a dataframe with one column as follows:

```
input
------------------------------------------
[NULL, ABC TGF FDSERV, GHD FGVCF TR UYF]
[NULL, GTR ygvv, HYTR FGVF, GTF BGHY GHYN]
[NULL]
[NULL, GTY DFERFT GHU FRTG]
```

Now, we can use `expr` function in pyspark to transform the input column to get the first word of each string of the array.

```
df = df.withColumn("output", expr("filter(transform(input, x -> split(x, ' ')[0]), x -> x is not null)"))
df.select("output").show()

output
----------------
[ABC, GHD]
[GTR, HYTR, GTF]
[]
[GTY]
```

Furthermore, in case you want **null** instead of empty array (for cases such as row 3) you can further do the following:

```
df = df.withColumn("output", when(size("output") == 0, None).otherwise(col("output")))
df.select("output").show()
```

Output:

| output |
| --- |
| [ABC, GHD] |
| [GTR, HYTR, GTF] |
| NULL |
| [GTY] |